# fread error - segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, fwrite, fread

Here is my code
Name of file *filewrite.c*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{

    int *p; 
    *p = 5;
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("sample.txt","w");
    fwrite(&p,sizeof(int),1,fp1);
    fclose(fp1);

    printf("\n Value of p written into the file is :%d \n",*p);

 int *q;
 FILE *fp2 = fopen("sample.txt","r");
 fread(&q,sizeof(int),1,fp2);
 fclose(fp2);

 printf("\n Value of q read from the file is :%d \n",*q);

 }
```

Output as seen on the terminal on linux:

```
$>gcc -o filewrite.o filewrite.c

$>filewrite.o

$>Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am able to see a file `sample.txt` written out. But unable to understand why there is a core dump.

Comment: `p` and `q` shouldn't be pointers. Change it to `int p = 5;` and `int q;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
fread(&q,sizeof(int),1,fp2);
```

to

```
fread(q,sizeof(int),1,fp2);
```

The first argument to `fread` is a `void *` and you are passing it a `pointer to pointer to int`

---

And, allocate memory for the pointer `p`

```
int *p;
p = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

same goes for `q`

```
int *q;
q = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: I Tried doing your change. Still I am getting segmentation fault

Comment: Well played....Another customer satisfied without even trying to think for an own solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
int *p; 
*p = 5;
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you try to write to unitialized memory. Without an explicit allocation, `p` points to *some* memory address which is most likely not accessible from your program.

You need to allocate memory to `p` before you can dererefernce it.

That said, your usage of [`fwrite()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) and [`fread()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) are problematic. You are passing a pointer-to-pointer-to `int` whereas you need to pass a pointer to `void`.

If you change the type of `p` and `q` from `int *` to `int`, I believe that will solve your issue.

That said,

- `void main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least, to conform to the standards.
- Always check for the return value of `fopen()` against NULL for success before using the returned file pointer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your help, but I am still facing issue, please check my code once . .

 void main()
{

int *p; 
p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*p = 5;
FILE *fp1 = fopen("sridhar.txt","w");
fwrite(&p,sizeof(int),1,fp1);
fclose(fp1);

printf("\n Value of p written into the file is :%d \n",*p);

int *q;
FILE *fp2 = fopen("sridhar.txt","r");
q = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
fread(q,sizeof(int),1,fp2);
fclose(fp2);

printf("\n Value of q read from the file is :%d \n",*q);

}


Value of p written into the file is :5 

 Value of q read from the file is :34000912

Comment: void main()
    {
    
    int *p; 
     p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
     *p = 5;
     FILE *fp1 = fopen("sridhar.txt","w");
     fwrite(&p,sizeof(int),1,fp1);
     fclose(fp1);

      printf("\n Value of p written into the file is :%d \n",*p);

      int *q;
      FILE *fp2 = fopen("sridhar.txt","r");
      q = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
      fread(q,sizeof(int),1,fp2);
      fclose(fp2);

      printf("\n Value of q read from the file is :%d \n",*q);

       }

Comment: @Sridhar Just a bit of advice, when you know the size to be allocated at compile time, why use dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, same problem with `q` variable.

Comment: @Haris Once OP grasp the concept, that should not be too hard to understand, However, thanks, updated.

Comment: Hi Sourav, Please suggest how to do memory allocation. I am new to C programming of this sort.

Comment: @Sridhar change `int *p` to `int p`, `int * q` to `int q`.

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested by you guys, I have made modification to my code and I am able to get proper output  . . Thanks a lot for your time guys ..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

int *p; 
p = malloc(sizeof(int));
*p = 5;
FILE *fp1 = fopen("sridhar.txt","w");
 fwrite(p,sizeof(int),1,fp1);
 fclose(fp1);

 printf("\n Value of p written into the file is :%d \n",*p);

int *q;
FILE *fp2 = fopen("sridhar.txt","r");
q = malloc(sizeof(int));
fread(q,sizeof(int),1,fp2);
fclose(fp2);

 printf("\n Value of q read from the file is :%d \n",*q);

 return 0;
 }
```

Output of the Code is as below:

Value of p written into the file is :5 
 Value of q read from the file is :5

Thanks again for your help @Saurav and Haris

Comment: Instead of using `malloc()`, what is the reason for not using `int p`, simply?